# ControllerAdvice not catching exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am learning java and using spring boot to develop web app. I am using @controllerAdvice to catch all the exceptions but none of my exceptions is being intercepted by it. I am using spring boot 2.6.2. git repo https://github.com/jitenderchand1/java-microservices

**Controller file**

```
package com.learning.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user-service")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoService service;

    @GetMapping(path = "/users")
    public List<User> retrieveAllUser() {
        return service.getAllUser();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/users/{id}")
    public User retrieveOneUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        User user = service.fineOne(id);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UserNotFoundException("id -" + id);
            //throw new Exception();
        }
        return user;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/user/save")
    public ResponseEntity<User> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User savedUser = service.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity(savedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**custom Exception handler**

```
package com.learning.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.user;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import java.util.Date;


@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomException extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), "I messed up", request.getDescription(true));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFoundException(UserNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(new Date(), "You are not from this world",
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Try to log if the user is null when the user is not found. 
2. Remove `@RestController` for `CustomException`.
Maybe try to attach the `Exception` and `UserNotFoundException` Java Class too so others can check for you.

Comment: I had this issue recently and was solved when adding `@Component` annotation. You can try to add `@Component` to the Advice class `CustomException` (`@ControllerAdvice` should stay too). And as Christopher suggests above - try to remove the `@RestController` annotation from `CustomException`.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that I have not included the getter in my Exception bean class. Stupid me :(

Comment: you can use `@RestControllerAdvice` instead of `@ControllerAdvice` + `@RestController` btw

Comment: Thanks @tknkrtl This was the simple fix. This is the correct answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

As @tknkrtl said in a simple comment,

> you can use @RestControllerAdvice instead of @ControllerAdvice +
> @RestController

So, simply exchange `@ControllerAdvice` with `@RestControllerAdvice` and [Bob's your uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle).